# Passing user entered text to following segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a screen with a text field.

When a user inputs text into that text field, and taps out of the text field, a segue occurs.

The following screen's label text should be changed to the text entered by the user in the previous.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        inputField.delegate = self

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        inputField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(inputField: UITextField) {
        let info = inputField.text
        print(info)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToBlue", sender: info)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goToBlue" {
            if let blueVC = segue.destinationViewController as? BlueViewController {
                if let sentValue = sender as? String {
                    blueVC.receptacle = sentValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `print(info)` statement does not print anything

However, the segue works, but the label displays nothing.

```
class BlueViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var blueText: UILabel!
    var receptacle = ""

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        blueText.text = receptacle
    }
}
```

Clearly this has to do with timing... any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the line where you set the blueVC.receptacle to make sure that code path is actually hit?

Comment: @HugoTunius I haven't, however even the `print(info)` statement does not print anything

Comment: Are you setting the text field's delegate from the storyboard? If not you should add `inputField.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad

Comment: @HugoTunius Gotcha, it prints now, however the following screen does not display the text ..

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `blueVC.receptacle = sentValue` and make sure it is hit

Comment: @HugoTunius done, the line gets highlighted in green and prints out `Optional("the message I enter")` to console

Comment: Okay, try changing when you set the value in the new VC from `viewWillAppear:` to `viewWillLoad:` I am not sure, but it's likely that `viewWillAppear:` is called before `prepareForSegue:` and thus setting the value is done too late.

Comment: @HugoTunius I do not see a viewWillLoad

Comment: No you'll have to add it yourself

Comment: @HugoTunius sorry I meant when I try to type it in, there is no autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Your viewWillAppear function works first and that time your receptacle variable is not set or your label does not initialized. Try this;

```
 @IBOutlet weak var blueText: UILabel! { didSet { blueText.text = receptacle } }

var receptacle: String? { didSet { blueText.text = receptacle } }
```

Comment: That seems overly complicated for what I am trying to do. Is there another way?

Comment: this is the right way. But if you want you can put your blueText.text = receptacle code in viewDidLoad function.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    blueText.text = receptacle
}

Comment: Do you have navigation controller ? Did you connect your segues with push segue ?

Comment: No i do not and did not

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    blueText.text = receptacle
}
```

to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    blueText.text = receptacle
}
```

Comment: you can't pass info as sender, well you can but it doesnt work. I gave you an answer above, check it out

Comment: I suspected as much, but I wasn't sure. Upvoted your answer since it's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very common way to do it (FYI, if the vc with inputTextfield is a popover, you can just call dismissViewController on the presenting vc)

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(inputField: UITextField) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        let info = inputField.text
        print(info)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToBlue", sender: info)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToBlue" {
            if let blueVC = segue.destinationViewController as? BlueViewController {
                blueVC.receptacle = self.inputField.text
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But that's not what i want. I want the event to occur when the user taps out of the textfield

Comment: Well you can use the same structure in textFieldEndEditing. Btw, is it still not working? (I edited my answer)

Comment: Do you have it on github?

Comment: i am pretty sure this has to do with timing, because when i place `print(sentValue)` in prepareForSegue, it outputs the right value, however when i place `print(receptacle)` in the other ViewController, it prints out an empty string

Comment: If by works fine you mean the animation, yeah it works fine! I even changed the value of receptacle in BlueViewController to `receptacle = "fail"` to see whether the label gets updated, and it does!

Comment: Lol, you're missing one line of code. inputField.delegate = self in right under super.viewDidLoad()
I run it and works fine ;)

Comment: no I have it :/ the guy in the comments id'ed that bug .... It still doesnt work.... just edited the question

Comment: sure I'll give you a github link

Comment: are you gonna post the link here ?

Comment: sorry, it took me a while to remember my github password.

Comment: I can email you a zipped copy if you wanna run it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90754/discussion-between-rayday-and-lukas).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `sender` to pass your value. The `sender` is only useful to check which element has started the segue, but not to pass data. Just make your `info` as a class-variable and pass the value like that:

```
var info:String!

func textFieldDidEndEditing(inputField: UITextField) {
    info = inputField.text
    print(info)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("goToBlue", sender: info)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToBlue" {
        if let blueVC = segue.destinationViewController as? BlueViewController {
             blueVC.receptacle = info
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This crashes my app `unexpectedly found nil (...) optional value` :(

Comment: Furthermore I would like to understand why my code doesn't work

Comment: Where does it crash? On which line?

Comment: `blueVC.receptacle = info`  @Christian

Comment: But I would really rather understand how to fix what I have